# Getting coordinates CLLocationManager IOS

Tags: ios, gps, cllocationmanager, cllocation

I'm trying to getting my current location exact according to my coordinates. I've implemented `CLLocationManager` in my `viewController` called `myLocation`.
My problem is, I'm getting not getting my co-ordinates for the first time, but when I again approach I got the coordinates. I'm unable to understand this problem that why this not appear for the first time.
I also tried to give a `NSTimer` to `stoplocation` but but still unable to get the result for the first time, every first time I getting a (null) value, and then getting the co-ordinates.

**My Code:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Corelocation/CoreLocation.h>
@interface myLocation : UITableViewController<CLLocationManagerDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;

@end

@interface myLocation () {
    CLLocationManager* _locationManager;
    NSString * _lat;
    NSString * _lng;
}
@end

@implementation myLocation

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    _locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    _locationManager.delegate = self;
    _locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
        [_locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];

    [_locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
     didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
    CLLocation *location = [locations lastObject];
    [_locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    _lat =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",location.coordinate.latitude];
     _lng =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",location.coordinate.longitude];
}
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL) animated
{
 NSLOG(@"%@",_lat);   
 NSLOG(@"%@",_lng);       
}
```

Comment: Oh, you mean why aren't your coordinates printing in viewWillAppear?

Comment: yeah, only for the first time. @LyndseyScott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your coordinates aren't appearing yet when you attempt to print them in `viewWillAppear:` because the `CLLocationManager` hasn't had enough time to retrieve the first location yet.  Wait until `didUpdateLocations:` is first called before attempting to utilize the device coordinates because `didUpdateLocations:` is where you'll be receiving those coordinates. I recommend deleting your attempt to print the coordinates code from your `viewWillAppear` and simply print them in `didUpdateLocations:` instead.

In the comments, the OP stated he wants to "refresh" the location during `viewWillAppear`. I suggest stopping the updates when the view disappears and restarting the updates as soon as the view reappears:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL) animated
{
    [_locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL) animated
{
    [_locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}
```

Comment: Your sugesstion is appreciabble for me, a little bit probelm remains in my secenario. I'm just callling in viewWillAppear so that every time it loads freshly, whenever it just clicked, its all refreshed. a possible scenario, if user haven't internet connection, and after that he got, what can he do to refesh. any suggestions for that ?

Comment: I got the solution, initialization in viewwillapear helped me. Thanks

Comment: @user3166680 I actually was just typing out a similar suggestion, but no need to completely reinitialize your location manager. I've updated my answer with a suggestion to just stop and restart your locations manager when the view disappears and reappears.

Answer (score 0):

It takes some time for location services to start up and call your delegate method - This almost certainly won't happen before `viewWillAppear` is called if you are only starting location services in `viewDidLoad`. Also, the first time your app executes it has to wait for the user to grant permission.

You can examine the `location` property of your `CLLocationManager` to get the most recent location.  If it is `nil` then no location has been determined (yet).